# jruby tomcat bundler aws -- `resolve requirement` stack too deep

Tags: tomcat, jruby, bundler, warbler, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been trying to deploy a bundled war file of my rails 3.1.3 app to an amazon beanstalk instance (which is just amazon ec2 with additional management software.)

When the app boots, it spits this out:

```
from /opt/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:286:in `resolve'
    from /opt/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /opt/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /opt/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'
    from /opt/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/gems/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:215:in `resolve'

    at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory$4.init(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:206)
    at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory.getApplication(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:56)
    at org.jruby.rack.SharedRackApplicationFactory.init(SharedRackApplicationFactory.java:27)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (SystemStackError) stack level too deep
```

Ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by running `bundle install --deployment`, and then re running warbler.

See this bundler issue: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/927#issuecomment-4043313